# How to handle uninterested missing (unobserved) data?

Tags: missing-data, stan

Suppose I have $N$ items $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^N$ (also denote the feature vector as $x_n$) and I have observed $M$ pairwise preferences $\{x_{i_m} \succ x_{j_m}\}_{m=1}^M$ from a user. Now I want to predict this user's preference on an unseen pair $x_i$ and $x_j$.

I first assume a utility function $f\sim\mathcal{GP}(0,\Sigma)$, such that $f(x_i) > f(x_j) \Leftrightarrow x_i \succ x_j \Leftrightarrow y_{ij} = 1$. Then I suppose the probability of the preference is given by

$$
\Pr(y_{ij}=1)=\frac{1}{1+\exp[f(x_j)-f(x_i)]}
$$

The generative model looks fine to me. But where should I put the matrix $Y=(y_{ij})_{n\times n}$ in Stan? If I put it into the `data` block, it seems I need to provide all the entries. It is also unrealistic to put the missing part into the `parameters` block because I am not interested in most of other preferences. So what is the correct way to do this in Stan? I somehow feel the `increment_log_prob` function may help but not sure how to. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this question is about `stan`. If I understand correctly, you essentially have only two options. One is to delete the incomplete information you don't care about (probably wasteful and fraught with hazards), and the other is to model the missing data explicitly and average over its posterior when summarizing quantities of interest. But you'd face this choice using any software tool.